# Preposition in or at

Tags: grammar

> I am writing this letter to express my disappointment with a recent purchase on your online store, order number #7298883.

Is the above sentence correct (i.e., the preposition **on** after purchase)?

I think **at** should be used but the IELTS blog site corrected it and has used **I made in** in place of **on**.

[Here](https://www.ielts-blog.com/ielts-writing-samples/ielts-letters-band-8/ielts-letter-topic-a-complaint-about-a-purchase-made-online/) is a link.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually argue for something different:

> I am writing this letter to express my disappointment with a recent purchase **I made** ***from*** your online store.

While I agree that **at** is a better preposition than **in** (which I find quite strange; you don't go *in* a website, you go *to* a website), I think that **from** works the best of all.

When you buy something **from** a store, it doesn't matter if it's a brick-and-mortar store or an online store. So, using **from** avoids the semantic difficulty of saying that you are either *in* or *at* an online store.

---

As for the use of **I made**, it makes it clear that *you* are the person who bought the item—and also frames it in an active construction rather than a passive construction. Not using *I made* is certainly not ungrammatical, but IELTS may be making a stylistic point.